# In MPAndroidChart, how to split X axis label into two lines? Not interested in using any modified library

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Setting Custom X Axis renderer doesn't help to split x axis labels in multiple lines at horizontal bar chart.

```
barChart.setXAxisRenderer(CustomXAxisRenderer(barChart.viewPortHandler, xAxis, barChart.getTransformer(yAxis.axisDependency)))
```

I am not interested in using any modified version of MPAndroidChart Library.

```
class CustomXAxisRenderer(viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler?, xAxis: XAxis?, trans: Transformer?) : XAxisRenderer(viewPortHandler, xAxis, trans) {
        override fun drawLabel(c: Canvas?, formattedLabel: String, x: Float, y: Float, anchor: MPPointF?, angleDegrees: Float) {
            val line: List<String> = formattedLabel.split("\n")
            Utils.drawXAxisValue(c, line[0], y, x, mAxisLabelPaint, anchor, angleDegrees)
            for (i in 1 until line.size) { // we've already processed 1st line
                Utils.drawXAxisValue(c, line[i], y, x + mAxisLabelPaint.textSize * i,
                    mAxisLabelPaint, anchor, angleDegrees)
            }
        }
    }
```

Kindly let me know any solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   class CustomXAxisRenderer(viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler?, xAxis: XAxis?, trans: Transformer?, chart: HorizontalBarChart) : XAxisRendererHorizontalBarChart(viewPortHandler, xAxis, trans, chart) {
        override fun drawLabel(c: Canvas?, formattedLabel: String, x: Float, y: Float, anchor: MPPointF?, angleDegrees: Float) {
            val line: List<String> = formattedLabel.split("\n")
            Utils.drawXAxisValue(c, line[0], x, y, mAxisLabelPaint, anchor, angleDegrees)
            for (i in 1 until line.size) {
                Utils.drawXAxisValue(c, line[i], x, y + mAxisLabelPaint.textSize * i,
                    mAxisLabelPaint, anchor, angleDegrees)
            }
        }
    }
```

This solves the above problem.